# Getting the sum duration of specific cell based on the usercolumn

Tags: google-apps-script

I am current working on a Utilization tool wherein I need to get the duration of the time from the first timestamp to the next.

I've already created a loop to get those duration. However, I am having trouble getting the right logic on it.

```
function Duration() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var validation_file = SpreadsheetApp.openById("some id here");
  var logged_act_sheet = validation_file.getSheetByName("Logged 
Activites");


  // Get the last row with data for the whole sheet.
  var numRows = logged_act_sheet.getLastRow();

  for(a=2; a < numRows; a++){
    var ldap = logged_act_sheet.getRange('C' + a).getValue();
    var ldapCount = a;
    for(b=ldapCount; b < numRows; b++){ 
    var ldap2 = logged_act_sheet.getRange('C' + b).getValue();
      if(ldap == ldap2 ){
        logged_act_sheet.getRange('D' + a).setFormula("=SUM(A" + b + 
"-A" + a + ")");
        }
    }
  }

};
```

Timestamp is in Colunmn A
Username is in Column C
Duration is in Column D
I expect the output to be: If C2 = user 1 and C4 = user 1 then D2 shoud be "=A4-A2" 
If C3 = user 2 and C5 = user 2 then D3 should be "=A5-A3". See sample data below:

[image: here's the sample data]

That means every time I loop on each row whatever the next row with same username from the active row will be the minuend and the subtrahend will be the active row.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved my own problem. I just need to add +1 on the ldapCount. var ldapCount = a + 1;